# What should be the correct form of 'be' verb in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tenses, descriptive-grammar, grammaticality

So I was asked to rewrite the following sentence with the correct tense of the verb given in bracket:
***It is I who (be) to do it.***
Initially I believed, the following would be correct:
***It is I who has to do it.***
But after researching for a while I think I am wrong and the ***has*** verb needs to be replaced with ***am***. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "It is you who are mistaken!" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57954/is-it-is-you-who-are-mistaken-correct) See also [He was to get an ice cream, is to , was to . Be to + infinitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138857/he-was-to-get-an-ice-cream-is-to-was-to-be-to-infinitive)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It is I who am at fault?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68919/it-is-i-who-am-at-fault) // niamulbengali's find is a few months earlier. //// Obviously, the question is asking for the correct form/s of 'be' here; has/have do not fulfil question requirements, whether they give grammatical sentences or not.

Comment: An actual answer would help.

Comment: From John Lawler at the duplicate (tailored): "Verb agreement is invariant under clefting, so if the predicate is 'am to do it' in the original (ie 'I am to do it'),
it will still be 'am to do it' in the clefted variant." ==> 'It is I who am to do it.'

Comment: Please suggest an appropriate answer. Has/have are forms of be verb, aren't they? Please help.

Comment: No, they're not. Please (1) respect that duplication is not seen as helpful to ELU's primary goals, (2) read John Lawler's answer addressing clefting, and (3) realise that "Aren't _has/have_ parts of the verb _be_?" shows a real need to get to grips with basics, far before addressing cleft structures.

Comment: In relative clauses like this, you have a choice: "It is **I** who **am** to do it" (simple agreement) or the less formal "It is **me** who **is** to do it" (3rd person override). But, depending on context, you could have "It is I who have to do it", or "it is me who has to do it" (both with a strong meaning of obligation equivalent to "must").

Answer (score 0):

"Is" could be the right form. There are plenty of examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+i+who+is+to%22&safe=active&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqnd_F3q3uAhUEdxoKHZarBIgQ_AUICigA&biw=1238&bih=831&dpr=1).

- And it is I who is to restore the fruits of my labor to the entire world.

However, this usage is  reckoned with as a common mistake ([The Most Common Mistakes in the English Language](https://books.google.fr/books?id=BNwuDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT74&lpg=PT74&dq=%22is+i+who+is+to%22&source=bl&ots=_yfO3zJJg5&sig=ACfU3U2P9JcVnuHUqeo4fGKrpfkqPNkJww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwil1ffZ3q3uAhWrx4UKHR7GDDUQ6AEwLHoECBQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22is%20i%20who%20is%20to%22&f=false)), and you should really use "**am**".

- It is I who am to do it.

Comment: Is the sentence "It is I who have to do this" grammatically right?

Comment: @Jonak It should be, the principle is the same; but in this case also you find "has" a lot. This is a little like "It's me": it is called correct nowadays, although you can still say "It is I."

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't include the verb _to be_!